# Javascript object programming and object representation

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, constructor

**Scenario**

I was toying with some Javascript object programming, when I wrote down the following code (demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJmu6/)):

```
    var o = {
        "key":1,
        "value": 1234,
        toString: function(){
            var res = this.key + ";" + this.value;
            return res;
        }
    };

    var p = {
        "key":2,
        "value": 5678
    };

    document.write(o);
    document.write("</br>");
    document.write(p);
```

As you can see, having a toString() method let the `o object` to be displayed without calling the toString() method, while the `p object` is displayed as... as what?

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is the `toString` literal a kind of default name for objects representation? Or what else?
2. What does the `[object Object]` notation mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody. You gave me references and good points. I started using Javascript a long time ago, before famous frameworks let everybody know the power of this scripting language. Now I am fascinated by oop capabilities of the ECMA-262: the old good Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the toString literal a kind of default name for objects representation? Or what else?

It is a function on the `toString` property of your object.

In Javascript, when an object is casted to a string ([EcmaScript §9.8: ToString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8), e.g. when used in a string concatenation, or in `alert()` or `document.write()`) it's `toString` method is called (via [ToPrimitive](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) and [DefaultValue - §8.12.8](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)).

Often, you specify that on the prototype of your custom objects, and also all builtin types have one (e.g. `Array.prototype.toString`, which joins the values with commata). You have explicitly set it in your object literal.

> What does the [object Object] notation mean?

This is the result of the default `toString` implementation of objects, ie. for all instances of `Object`. [EcmaScript §15.2.4.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) specifies `Object.prototype.toString` to return `[object`+*class*+`]`, and the internal [[class]] of plain objects is "Object".

Answer (score 1):

toString is not a literal, it is a function and is defined for all objects.  Remember functions are "first class" in javascript.

The `[object Object]` is the return value of the browser's default toString() for an object.

Here is Mozilla's excellent documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: No, it does not look different

Comment: +1 one for the reference and the remark about the "first class"!

Answer (score 0):

1. When an object is sent to write, write internally calls the toString method of the object which might (like in o) or might not (like in p) be overridden.
2. In the default implementation of toString, the first `object` defines that it is an object (in contrary to an array or primitive) and the second `Object` defines that it is an object of type Object. Some build-in object types which don't have a meaningful string represenation (like DOM nodes, for example), return their type name instead of Object. When you want your own objects to output their type name when passed to write, you have to override toString.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in JavaScript has a `toString()` method, which gets called implicitly when the object is used in a string context, such as with `document.write(o)` but also when you write `o + ' another string'`.

The method returns `'[object Object]'` by default which is not very useful, but it can be overridden to return anything you like; Objects like `Numeric`, `String` or `Date` do this for instance.

Answer (score -1):

'[object Object]' is returned by the default `toString` method which is inherited by every object descended from `Object`.